# how to SELECT and Concat() column values based on several conditions SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, db2, concatenation, join

newbie here to SQL. So I have two tables, let's take for example the two tables below.

Table A

```
set_num   s_id   s_val
100        3      AA 
100        5      BB
200        3      AA
200        9      CC
```

Table B

```
s_id    s_val    phrase        seq 
1        DD      'hi'         'first'
3        AA      'hello'      'first'
6        EE      'goodnight'  'first'
5        BB      'world'      'second'
9        CC      'there'      'second'
4        FF      'bye'        'first'
```

I want to join Table A with Table B on two columns, like a composite key (s_id, s_val), and I want to return
**set_num** from Table A and the concatenation of phrases in Table B (which we will call **entire_phrase**, concat(...) AS entire_phrase).
The concatenation should also follow an order in which the phrases are to be concatenated. This will be determined by seq column in Table B for each phrase. "First" will indicate this phrase needs to come first and "Second", well comes next. I will like to do this with a SELECT query but not sure if this is possible without it getting to complex. Can I do this in SELECT or does this call for another approach?

Expected Output:

```
set_num    entire_phrase
100        'hello world'
200        'hello there'
```

And not

```
set_num    entire_phrase
100        'world hello'
200        'there hello'
```

Any help/approach will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have exactly two records for every `set_num` with one marked as "first" and another as "second" in Table A?

Comment: Do you really need it for 3 different RDBMS?

Comment: In mysql it's easy with group_concat().

Comment: Sorry. Mysql should not be included as This is for db2. @PMy77-1. I've been told it's a for sure thing that I'll have a fixed number of recs per set and each will have a unique value to determine which comes first. ..etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
select temp1.set_num, concat(phrase1,' ',phrase2) as entire_phrase
from (
(
select set_num, b.phrase as phrase1
from TableA as A
join TableB as B
on a.s_id = b.s_id 
and a.s_val = b.s_val 
and b.seq = 'first'
) as temp1
join 
(
select set_num, b.phrase as phrase2 
from TableA as A
join TableB as B
on a.s_id = b.s_id 
and a.s_val = b.s_val 
and b.seq = 'second' 
) as temp2
on temp1.set_num = temp2.set_num
)
```

Running here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d63ac3/1

Comment: thank u. I will give it a shot and let u know. Qq...if each set can have various number of phrases then just have additional joins?

Comment: Yes, assuming all are mandatory. Also, if there are many more, there would be better ways to solve it. I just went for "fairly simple to understand" here.